# Assigning values in a continuous sequence depending on second column

Tags: r

I'd like to assign a sequence to a column of TRUE or FALSE values, with the sequence holding the same value for the TRUE following one OR many consecutive FALSE values.

i.e what i'm trying to replicate is this;

```
df <- data.frame(
new_activity = as.character(c("TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE",
              "TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE")),
sequence = as.numeric(c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,14,14,15,16,16)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your column to type `logical`, use `cumsum` first and then add the negation of the input vector to get desired output

```
x <- as.logical(df$new_activity)
cumsum(x) + !x
# [1]  1  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 14 14 15 16 16
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to convert the 'new_activity' to `logical`, place it on the `i`, create column 'sequence1' as the sequence of rows, then pad the `NAs` with `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[as.logical(new_activity), sequence1 := seq_len(.N)
       ][, sequence1 := na.locf(sequence1, fromLast = TRUE)]
df
#    new_activity sequence sequence1
# 1:         TRUE        1         1
# 2:         TRUE        2         2
# 3:         TRUE        3         3
# 4:        FALSE        4         4
# 5:         TRUE        4         4
# 6:         TRUE        5         5
# 7:         TRUE        6         6
# 8:         TRUE        7         7
# 9:         TRUE        8         8
#10:         TRUE        9         9
#11:         TRUE       10        10
#12:         TRUE       11        11
#13:         TRUE       12        12
#14:         TRUE       13        13
#15:        FALSE       14        14
#16:        FALSE       14        14
#17:         TRUE       14        14
#18:         TRUE       15        15
#19:        FALSE       16        16
#20:         TRUE       16        16
```